# Unable to install Python in RHEL 8 using subscription-manager

Tags: python, rhel8

I've been unsuccessful in installing Python (versions 2 or 3) in a RHEL 8.2 EC2 Host.
Error : Unable to find a match: python

No match for argument: python3
Error: Unable to find a match: python3

I've captured below available repo list in the Host.

```
# subscription-manager list
+-------------------------------------------+
    Installed Product Status
+-------------------------------------------+
Product Name:   Red Hat Enterprise Linux for x86_64
Product ID:     123
Version:        8.2
Arch:           x86_64
Status:         Subscribed
Status Details: 
Starts:         03/01/2020
Ends:           03/01/2021

# subscription-manager repos --list
+----------------------------------------------------------+
    Available Repositories in /etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo
+----------------------------------------------------------+
Repo ID:   satellite-tools-6.7-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.7 for RHEL 8 x86_64 (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://ip-210-14-0-32.us-west-2.compute.internal/pulp/repos/Concur/Library/RHEL_8/content/dist/layered/rhel8/x86_64/s
           at-tools/6.7/os
Enabled:   1
Repo ID:   rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://ip-10-214-10-32.us-west-2.compute.internal/pulp/repos/Concur/Library/RHEL_8/content/dist/rhel8/$releasever/x86_
           64/appstream/os
Enabled:   1
Repo ID:   rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://ip-10-214-10-32.us-west-2.compute.internal/pulp/repos/Concur/Library/RHEL_8/content/dist/rhel8/$releasever/x86_
           64/baseos/os
Enabled:   1
Repo ID:   ansible-2.8-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Ansible Engine 2.8 for RHEL 8 x86_64 (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://ip-10-214-10-32.us-west-2.compute.internal/pulp/repos/Concur/Library/RHEL_8/content/dist/layered/rhel8/x86_64/a
           nsible/2.8/os
Enabled:   1
Repo ID:   rh-gluster-3-client-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Storage Native Client for RHEL 8 (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://ip-10-214-10-32.us-west-2.compute.internal/pulp/repos/Concur/Library/RHEL_8/content/dist/layered/rhel8/x86_64/r
           hgs-client/3.5/os
Enabled:   1
Repo ID:   rhv-4-tools-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Virtualization 4 Tools for RHEL 8 x86_64 (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://ip-10-214-0-32.us-west-2.compute.internal/pulp/repos/Concur/Library/RHEL_8/content/dist/layered/rhel8/x86_64/r
           hv-tools/4/os
Enabled:   1
Collapse

-------------

# sudo yum install python
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS (RPMs)                                            42 kB/s | 2.1 kB     00:00    
Red Hat Ansible Engine 2.8 for RHEL 8 x86_64 (RPMs)                                              47 kB/s | 2.3 kB     00:00    
Red Hat Virtualization 4 Tools for RHEL 8 x86_64 (RPMs)                                          48 kB/s | 2.3 kB     00:00    
Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.7 for RHEL 8 x86_64 (RPMs)                                             44 kB/s | 2.1 kB     00:00    
Red Hat Storage Native Client for RHEL 8 (RPMs)                                                  48 kB/s | 2.3 kB     00:00    
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)                                         43 kB/s | 2.1 kB     00:00    
No match for argument: python
Error: Unable to find a match: python


# subscription-manager repos --enable=*
Repository 'rhv-4-tools-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms' is enabled for this system.
Repository 'rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms' is enabled for this system.
Repository 'ansible-2.8-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms' is enabled for this system.
Repository 'rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms' is enabled for this system.
Repository 'rh-gluster-3-client-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms' is enabled for this system.
Repository 'satellite-tools-6.7-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms' is enabled for this system.
--------------
```

I tried unsuccessfully the commands - sudo yum install python3, sudo yum install python2.

The output from *sudo yum search python3* , did not list a valid rpm for installation.